# Are tags you add yourself in Steam public or private?

Tags: steam

So lately I've been going through games I either see on the front page that i am interested in or games on my wish list and been adding a DRM tag hoping that it'll be easier to avoid games with DRM (and maybe stop Developers/Publishes in treating paying customers as if they are pirates). how I've tagged both in browser and in the Steam Application and they show up when i'm logged in

[image: Dragon Quest XI with the DRM Tag]

But when I go to check in Incognito mode in Chrome and I try to search by the tag I see nothing

[image: DRM not appearing]

I know a tag is supposed to appear as I tried a more well known tag and it appears before I even finished typing it

[image: Driving tag appearing with just driv]

It is my understanding [from Steam](https://store.steampowered.com/tag/) that tags are public

> ### BROWSE BY POPULAR TAGS
>
> Browse a new section of the Steam Store to discover games and software, organized by the most frequently used tags.
>
> Plus, narrow your search to just products tagged with the terms you **and your friends have applied**.

So I am wondering, are tags you add yourself in Steam public to all or private to just you and your friends?

Comment: I cannot see your DRM tag on the game, so I guess it is private. The alternative is to just ignore the game.

Answer (score 4):

Unapproved tags are not public:

> Some users add unapproved tags to games, either because it's helpful for them to have some metadata attached to the game for their own purposes or because we've missed approving some useful tag that legitimately should apply to that game.

[Source](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/tags)

Unapproved tags can be approved by the devs etc., but otherwise they only apply to you and anyone else you share those tags with. Once a tag has been approved, it will then become public.